# ValueError on Multi-index dataframe plotting with Seaborn boxplot with hue for category error

Tags: python, dataframe, seaborn, boxplot, multi-index

I am trying to create a boxplot for a multi-index dataframe. I have read the documentation for the seaborn boxplotting, but I keep getting an error.

The error I keep getting is:

```
ValueError: Could not interpret input 'Mining Method for graphs '
```

The dataframe is also given below:
[image]

The code to create the plot

```
sns.boxplot(x = 'Total production (ktpm)',y = 'Airflow\n(kg/s)',data =
DataFrame,hue= 'Mining Method for graphs ')

sns.boxplot(x = 'Total production (ktpm)',data = DataFrame,hue ='Mining Method for graphs ')
```

I don't understand why I cannot create a boxplots for the data by grouping it as with **hue**, for the mining method.

**Dictionary can be found below (doesn't create all the rows but should work):**

```
{'Total production (ktpm)': {('Platinum', 'Narrow reef ', 'RSA'): 200.0,
  ('Platinum', 'Bord and pillar', 'RSA'): 187.0,
  ('Platinum', 'Breast stoping ', 'RSA'): 120.0},
 'Airflow\n(kg/s)': {('Platinum', 'Narrow reef ', 'RSA'): 870.0,
  ('Platinum', 'Bord and pillar', 'RSA'): 480.0,
  ('Platinum', 'Breast stoping ', 'RSA'): 553.581}}
```

Please help. Would appreciate it very much.

Comment: does `data = DataFrame.reset_index(level=1)` help?

Comment: HI @SayandipDutta I reran the code by including your code. Still the same error and not able to plot.

Comment: By changing "data = DataFrame.reset_index(level=1, inplace =True)" then it works. Thanks